# Linux accessing SQL Server 2008 R2?

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, codeigniter, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm stuck on a real challenge here in my company. I've been programming for the last two months a ticket system based on openSUSE, Apache, PHP, MySQL and CodeIgniter for the framework.

Everything went fine since my company bought the impressive Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011. I know that Dynamics has a great ticket system inside too, but we're really late with our deadline and I think that learning to customize the Dynamics Ticket System will be difficult.

Now I need to access the Accounts, Contacts and Employees from Dynamics (SQL Server) and use them on my PHP and MySQL system for opening and delegating tickets.

Is there any way to make this possible? I need just a connection for retrieving these three data tables from SQL Server to accomplish my task on this system.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Yeah! I found it!

Basically I turned on the dynamic port on SQL Server and 1433 on TCP port on **IPALL**

And then on SELinux,

```
- setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect = 1
- setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect_db = 1
```

Geezus! I lost all my hair on that.

Comment: this does not answer your question.

Comment: and why does not answer ? explain to me

Comment: you never said that you had problems connecting.

Comment: sorry man. I tought that i did not need to reask this question since that my own answer corroborates with your answer about free dts.

Answer (score 2):

In the MSCRM database, you'll find a view for each of those entities.  If you are just trying to read data from CRM, that should work fine.  If you need to push data back, you'll need to call the CRM web services.  Updating the CRM database directly is not recommended or supported because you'll bypass all the application logic (plugins, workflows, security, etc).

Comment: No no. I just need to retrieve data from CRM such as Account, Contact and what employee id is opening the ticket.

Answer (score 1):

Sure! PHP has support for SQL Server. From *[Microsoft SQL Server](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mssql.php)* (PHP Manual):

> To use the MSSQL extension on Unix/Linux, you first need to build and
>   install the FreeTDS library. Source code and installation instructions
>   are available at the FreeTDS home page: » http://www.freetds.org/

Make sure you abstract it away nicely!

Comment: I need to recompile something on my linux server ? Is there any possibilty to crash the system ?

Comment: OK ! i used Fedora Distro and YUM installer automatically installed freetds. But it continues to the same error. I'm missing any config to allowing my linux server connect to the another server (windows server with sql server ?)

Comment: I add a rule on SQL SERVER firewall and now i'm able to access it by telnet (on my linux server). Ok, i tried this just to be sure that my linux server can access the SQL SERVER. Then i tried again to connect via PHP and get the following error: 
`Warning: mssql_connect(): Unable to connect to server: srv-13\db_sat`

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to write a web service that talks to MSCRM then your PHP/Linux consumes it.

Comment: And i write this Webservice on linux or windows server ?

Comment: on windows. mscrm might have some of this already written for you.